# Разделить текст на предложения. (Python)

Tags: python

Здравствуйте! 
Мне нужно разделить текст на предложения.

Я пробую делать так:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
text = 'A clam for supper? a cold clam; is THAT what you mean, Mrs. Hussey? says I, "but that\'s a rather cold and clammy reception in the winter time, ain\'t it, Mrs. Hussey?"'
print(sent_tokenize(text))
```

Получаю вывод:

```
>>> ['A clam for supper?', 'a cold clam; is THAT what you mean, Mrs. Hussey?', 'says I, "but that\'s a rather cold and clammy reception in the winter time, ain\'t it, Mrs.', 'Hussey?"']
```

Последнее предложение разделилось неправильно. Подскажите способы / библиотеки, с помощью которых можно решить эту проблему.

Это просто пример. Мне нужно распарсить большой текст на предложения. Не знаю, какие еще нюансы могут там возникнуть, поэтому напишите, какой токенайзер предложений по Вашему мнению наилучший (для английского языка).

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потыкав ваш пример, оказалось, что самые популярные токенайзеры как-то очень криво воспринимают кавычки, следующие сразу за знаком препинания: `Mrs. Hussey?"`, но отлично парсится `Mrs. Hussey? "`. Также отлично парсится `Mrs._Hussey?"` - без пробелов вокруг кавычек, но зато с модифицированным `Mrs.` Из этой ситуации не видно красивых выходов, а как извращаться это уже ваш выбор. Я бы сделал так - накопал бы список всех сокращений с точками. Для данного случая можно начать отсюда: [English honorifics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_honorifics). Далее заменял бы точки с пробелами после этих слов на точки с подчеркиваниями, а потом обратно. Можно регулярку написать или как-то так:

```
import nltk

blah_blah_with_dots = {'Dr', 'Ms', 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Prof', 'Inc', 'Fr'}

SENTENCE_TOKENIZER = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

text = 'A clam for supper? a cold clam; is THAT what you mean, Mrs. Hussey? says I, "but that\'s a rather cold and clammy reception in the winter time, ain\'t it, Mrs. Hussey?"'

for blah in blah_blah_with_dots:
    text = text.replace(blah + ". ", blah + "._")

for index, sentence in enumerate(SENTENCE_TOKENIZER.tokenize(text)):
    for blah in blah_blah_with_dots:
        sentence = sentence.replace(blah + "._", blah + ". ")
    print("Sentence: ", index, sentence)

print()
print("Full text: ", text)
```

Выглядит уродски, но ничего не поделаешь. Жизнь - боль. Можно попробовать заменять кавычки. Не зная внутренней кухни nltk сложно сказать кто виновник. Сразу советую подумать о том, чтобы заменять юникодные кавычки на православные `"` или `'` Или вот еще связанных вопросов:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095971/how-to-tweak-the-nltk-sentence-tokenizer/25375857#25375857

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941997/why-does-nltk-mis-tokenize-quote-at-end-of-sentence

Для того, чтобы установить какой токенайзер лучший необходимо придумать некий формальный набор тестов и смотреть кто и как себя поведет. Никогда не видел таких тестов, обычно все пользуют токенайзер по-умолчанию: [вот этот вот](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py). Он должен быть обучен на большом массиве текста - есть уже обученная модель, ее можно скачать вызвав метод `nltk.download()`. Конечно же, можно самому [обучить](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktTrainer) модель - был бы корпус подходящий.